# hide "everything" in sharepoint search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, people-search, mysite

I configured enterprise search in SP2013,i want to hide "Every thing" and "Videos" options,can any one help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit the search configuration by going to your search center site collection, go to site settings, and then search settings. Here you should be able to see the current navigation and be able to edit/hide/remove "Everything", "People" or "Videos".

[image]